# How to neatly push an object in another complex object in react state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-functional-component, react-state

I am trying to declare a complex array using react hook as

```
const [strategy, setStrategy] = useState([leg]);
```

where

```
const leg = {
  entry: {
    conditions: [],
    actions: [""],
  },
  exit: {
    conditions: [],
    actions: [""],
  },
};
```

and

```
const condition = (param) => {
  return { param, val: "" };
};
```

Now, the following code to add a leg in the array is working fine

```
const addLeg = () => {
    const temp_strategy = [...strategy];
    temp_strategy.push(leg);

    setStrategy(temp_strategy);
};
```

Now, I want to add a condition in one of the legs whose index is given (on a button click in the front-end), following is the code I am trying

```
  const addCondition = (index, trigger, condition_param) => {
    // index is for leg
    // trigger is either 'entry' or 'exit'

    const temp_strategy = [...strategy];

    temp_strategy[index][trigger]['conditions'].push(condition(condition_param));

    setStrategy(temp_strategy);
  };
```

Now if at some point strategy is having 3 legs and if I call

```
addCondition(1, 'entry', 'and')
```

then it is appending the above condition to all 3 legs but inside the 'entry' object.

My doubt is why it is not working for the index but it is working for the trigger where index and trigger are as

```
temp_strategy[index][trigger]['conditions'].push(condition(condition_param));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a beautiful library specially built for such a scenario `immer.js`. Go check this out at https://www.npmjs.com/package/immer

Comment: Thanks, Prasenjeet. It's an elegant library